# Grails findAll returns null properties inside 'each' closure

Tags: grails, groovy

Using findAll to get a list of Content without LocationGeoPoint.
I have to manually get every content because properties of content (content.location) are null inside the each closure. Is this because findAll does not actually fetch from the DB?

```
def contents = Content.findAllByLocationGeoPointIsNull()
def location
GeoPoint geoPoint
contents.each { Content content ->
    println content
    if(content.location == null) {
        content = Content.get(content.id)
    }
    location = content.location
    println content.location
    println location
    ...
    content.save()
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm guessing (as they are returned like that by the findAll) that they are simply null in the database

Answer (score 0):

I am probably misunderstanding your problem but here is my suggestion. You are requesting for all LocationGeoPoint where value is null, maybe you should try IsNotNull, you can read about it here http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#finders you can find there and example.

You could try something like this

```
List<Content> contents = Content.findAllByLocationGeoPointIsNotNull()

contents.each { Content content ->
    // update logic goes here

    content.save()
}
```

I also recommend you take a look at the where queries they allow you to execute batch updates and deletes.

Comment: I'm actually looking for null values of locationGeoPoint so I can set them. My problem is that I cannot access the properties of Content instances. Content.location is never null but I cannot access it unless I use this line `content = Content.get(content.id)`.

Comment: I understand, to be more accurate in the help share the definitions of the domain classes, just the relevant properties and relationships